# Thales Payshield command "JS"

Tags: hsm

Does anyone knows format of the "JS" command (ARQC Verification and/or ARPC Generation - CUP) in license HSM9-LIC031.
The "JS" command is China Union Pay commands.
I am using HSM, but i don't know the command format.
The command looks like `Command Code    2A    JS`.

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about JS command in Thales HSM documentation

> payShield 9000 v2.3b
>
> Host Command Reference Manual Addendum for Optional License LIC031 (CUP Commands)
>
> pages 4,5

Also in that section, you can find all about the format of JS command.